# iOS - What are best practices for view controller setup for a posts + comments data model?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller

Forgive me if this question has been asked elsewhere, I was having trouble finding similar questions.

So I have an app where I am displaying a list of posts, and each post has a list of comments, very similar to the way Instagram's home page is laid out.

**Current implementation**

The way I've implemented it, I'm using a single `UITableViewController` and I have an array of posts that back my data source. Each post object has it's own array of comment objects. In `numberOfRowsInSection` I iterate through the posts array and add up all the posts and comments to get the total number of rows. I have two `UITableViewCell` templates, one for posts and one for comments, and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and  `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` (and really any function that does anything significant) I have to do a bunch of logic just to get the right model or view for the given index path.

**Issues**

This setup seems to work okay, but is really difficult to debug and add features to. Especially now that I am trying to implement Pusher updates from the server, I am running into a lot of issues with how complicated the model to view relationship is and how long it takes to update the model before the view can be updated.

**Alternative Implementations I've considered**

I started reading a little about `UICollectonView`s and was thinking about using the supplementary views to show comments and having only the posts be regular cells, but I'm not sure if that's actually how collection views work or if it would make this any easier. I've also considered using only one cell template for the post + comments that dynamically adds comment views to itself as necessary, but I'm not even sure that's possible.

**Question**

Is there an easier way to implement a posts+comments layout that is better suited to the way the data is laid out?  This seems like a pretty common problem that's been solved by a lot of people so I'm hoping someone can point me to some best practices.

**Edit:** An example of what I mean. The part outlined in red is the comment section for the post, outlined in blue. Instagram seems to be making each post a section though, with the poster's name as a floating header, each post being it's own section seems like it would be easier to implement. I had initially tried to implement my app that way but ran into issues with making the section header much larger than default, maybe I should just change my design to better suit sections?

[image]

Comment: you want to show comments and post in the same tableview? can you show that screen or an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your main problem is that you are using different cells for "sub entities". So each time you have to reload multiple cells when updating one entity.

It doesn't really make a difference whether you chose the table or collection view. (Depending on the layout, but I guess Instagram is a table view too)

To make your view handling better / easier you should create a cell that handles all the properties of your entity. And for showing all comments you should probably switch to a new view controller. Or you could  use one section for one post. So you could just reload one section. The post could be the section header and the comments the cells in the section.

So you could access your cells easily. tableData[section].commments[row]. And then you could just insert a new row into the section when a comment is added.

I hope I understood your problem.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly my problem. Having each post be a section seems to be the best solution. I started implementing it and already the worst parts of my code are looking a lot better, don't know why I abandoned this approach.